# Upload multiplayer world to my own minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have access to a VPS and set up a Minecraft server with [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-minecraft-server-on-ubuntu-18-04) guide. Now, I am trying to move my world from minehut.com to my server. But, I could not find any guides to add world data besides my server files. How can I add the world data to my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *server.properties* from the guide you linked there's a line "level-name", equals by default to "world". This means that the "world" folder that is in the same directory of your server.jar executable is used as the server's world.

Just add your world folder in the same directory of your .jar and update the level-name in the *server.properties* with your world folder's name.